# Search users in Elasticsearch with NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

Today i have a database with all users, now i want to copy the users to elasticsearch. When i search users in the db, i use 2 sql queries,

- SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username LIKE 'An%' (for autocomplete)
- SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Username LIKE '%An%' (for free text search)

Now i want to do the same thing in elasticsearch. This is what i have:

```
 public static string IndexName => "users";


 public static List<UserInfo> FindUsersStartsWith(string name, int pageSize, int currentPage,
        ref long unitItems)
    {
            var Result = Client.Search<UserInfo>(s => s
                .Index(IndexName)
                .Query(q => q
                    .Match(m => m
                        // specify the field
                        .Field(f => f.UserName)
                        .Query(name)
                    )
                )
                .Size(pageSize)
                .From((currentPage - 1) * pageSize)
                );

            unitItems = Result.Total;
            return Result.Documents.ToList();            
    }

 public static List<UserInfo> FindUsersContains(string name, int pageSize, int currentPage,
        ref long unitItems)
    {
            var Result = Client.Search<UserInfo>(s => s
                .Index(IndexName)
                .Query(q => q
                    .Match(m => m
                        // specify the field
                        .Field(f => f.UserName)
                        .Query(name)
                    )
                )
                .Size(pageSize)
                .From((currentPage - 1) * pageSize)
                );

            unitItems = Result.Total;
            return Result.Documents.ToList();            
    }

    public static void SetUser(UserInfo ui)
    {
            if (!client.IndexExists(IndexName).Exists)
            {
                client.CreateIndex(IndexName);
            }

            Client.Update<UserInfo, UserInfo>
                (DocumentPath<UserInfo>
                    .Id(ui.UserNr), descriptor => descriptor.Doc(ui).DocAsUpsert().Refresh()
                );

    }

[Serializable, ElasticsearchType(IdProperty = "UserNr")]
public class UserInfo
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Avatar { get; set; }
    public int UserNr { get; set; }
}
```

**Edit:** My idea is to have 2 functions. One where i can search on users that starts with, "An" (upper- or lowercase doesn't matter) and returns users like "Andy", not "Ronan". The other function will return all users that contains "An" (upper- or lowercase doesn't matter).

Comment: Does it need to be exactly `An` (case sensitive)? Should `An` only be found at the start of word boundaries e.g. `An`dy, or can it be found anywhere within a word e.g. Ron`an`? Please edit your question to include any such restrictions, as this may affect the approach to take

Comment: Additionally, `ConnectionSettings` and `ElasticClient` can be singletons and live for the lifetime of your application; you can construct them at startup and reuse them and also check and create the index at startup too :)

Comment: For the autocomplete, did you consider the [completion suggester/field](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html)? If you don't want another field, consider the [match_phrase_prefix query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_query_time_search_as_you_type.html)

For your search, the [wildcard](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_wildcard_and_regexp_queries.html) may serve you well.

Comment: @RussCam I updated my question with more information.